# Building a string using fold, and would like to speed it up by assigning the correct capacity

Tags: rust, fold, pre-allocation

I have an implementation in a Rust struct that builds a very large string that will ultimately be written to a file.  I wondered if this could be sped up by ensuring the string variable has the appropriate capacity, but it doesn't work in the way I expected.

Here's what I did:

```
let sum = izip!(self.ts, self.x, self.y).fold(String::with_capacity(capacity), |acc, x| {
            format!("{}{}, {}, {}\n", acc, x.0, x.1, x.2)
        });
```

I thought that the string would be accumulated into the first argument, so I instantiated it with the necessary capacity. However, by checking the capacity of the string that is output from this (`sum`), I can see that my assumptions were wrong.

Can someone help me understand the way in which my understanding of `fold` is wrong? And perhaps give a hint as to a better way to do build this string?

Comment: hint: `format!` creates a new string every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `format!` will always produce a new `String`. Instead you can [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) to the existing string:

```
let sum = izip!(self.ts, self.x, self.y).fold(String::with_capacity(capacity), |mut acc, x| {
    let _ = write!(acc, "{}, {}, {}\n", x.0, x.1, x.2);
    acc
});
```

Make sure to import `std::fmt::Write` as well.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you. That got a x20 speed up in that part of the code :)
I already had std::io::Write imported, so I had to learn how to import two modules with the same name.  `use ... as ...`

Comment: @smolloy The so big speedup should probably be attributed more to the usage of `write!()` itself, avoiding allocating a new string every time, than to the capacity (but it also should do nice work).

Comment: @smolloy If you want to compare the speedup with and without `write!()`, you can measure a version that uses: `acc = acc.push_str(&format!("{}, {}, {}\n", x.0, x.1, x.2)); acc`. That will achieve your original intention of reusing `acc` (and its capacity reserved in advance) without applying kmdreko's additional optimization that avoids temporary allocations inside the loop.